# Laravel ajax send id before option is selected

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I try to make a search function by 4 dropdowns, which they load data's base of previous dropdown selected item.

## Logic

***field = Dropdown option***

Field 1 select `A`

Field 2 options `B` `C` (Select `B`)

Field 3 options `D` `E` (Select `E`)

Field 4 options `F` `G` (Select `F`) => Results.

## Problems

1. When I reach field 2 it sends `2` id's instead of one (which is selected item id) and it will count as field 3 id so I'm loosing ability of choosing field 3.
2. I cannot get results of field 4.

## Screenshots

`database logic`
[image: screen 1]

`front-end logic & issue`
[image: screen 2]

## Codes

`field one data`

```
$findercategories = FinderYmmValue::where('parent_id', null)->get();
```

`field 2 data, base on field one selected item`

```
public function getSubCategories($id){
        $finderdropdownvalues = FinderYmmValue::where('parent_id', $id)->get();
        return response()->json($finderdropdownvalues);
  }
```

`field 3 data, base on field two selected item`

```
public function getspecifications($id){
    $fdhgkhehg = FinderYmmValue::where('parent_id', $id)->get();
    return response()->json($fdhgkhehg);
  }
```

`field 4 data, base on field three selected item`

```
public function getbrands($id){
    // $fdhgkhehg = FinderMap::where('', $id)->get();
    // return response()->json($fdhgkhehg);
    $skus = DB::table('finder_maps')
                ->where('ymm_value_id', $id)
                ->join('finder_ymm_values', 'finder_ymm_values.id', '=', 'finder_maps.ymm_value_id')
                ->groupBy('ymm_value_id')
                ->get();
    return response()->json($skus);
  }
```

### JavaScript Codes

```
<!-- get field 2 items -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="category_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var categoryID = $(this).val();
      if(categoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getSubCategories') }}/'+encodeURI(categoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').append('<option value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['title'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- get field 3 items-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getspecifications') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                  $('select[name="specification_id"]').append(
                        "<option class='form-control' value='"+ value['id'] +"'>"+ value['title'] +"</option>");
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="specification_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- get field 4 items-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="subcategory_id"]').on('change', function() {
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getbrands') }}/'+encodeURI(subcategoryID),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
        $('select[name="brand_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[name="brand_id"]').append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['id'] +'">'+ value['sku'] +'</option>');
            });
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('select[name="brand_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

## Questions

1. Why is 2 id sent when I select my second field item?
2. Why I can't send my field 3 id when I select it?

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bound 2 event handlers to `select[name="subcategory_id"]` and none to `select[name="specification_id"]` that's why you get 2 request when you select the second option and none when you select the third.

Comment: Thanks man, silly mistake of me :), one last question: when I select my 3rd field my 4th field return only 1 result while i have 3 result. why is that? (probably something wrong in my function?)

Comment: fixed that, just need to remove `->groupBy('ymm_value_id')`.